# SQL Map column values to other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've got a pivoted query which is outputting something like:

```
[ID][Value][DateField1][Val1][Val2][Val3]
 1   R2     2014-01-01  0.3   3.2   3.1
 1   R1     2014-01-02  NULL  2.2   0.5
 1   R2     2014-01-02  0.7   NULL  NULL
```

I need to further modify it such that the Value Column is turned into:

```
[ID][DateField1][Val1][Val2][Val3][Val1R][Val2R][Val3R]
 1   2014-01-01  0.3   3.2   3.1   R2     R2     R2
 1   2014-01-02  0.7   2.2   0.5   R2     R1     R1
```

It wouldn't be a pivot but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Tell use more about the R-value calculation/transform. Is it a lookup or a calculation?

Comment: The R-value is just a plain lookup, there's no calculations being done. The Val1, Val2, Val3 columns are actually pivoted values but in order to display this information to the user, I need a single row per DateField. The R values are supposed to help color-code the information for Val1, Val2, Val3 columns on the display page.

Comment: I didn't even see that second column up there for some reason.

Comment: Maybe denormalize the output somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with D as (
    yourquery
)
select
    ID, DateField1,
    sum(Val1) as Val1,
    sum(Val2) as Val2,
    sum(Val3) as Val3,
    min(case when Val1 is not null then Value end) as Val1R,
    min(case when Val2 is not null then Value end) as Val2R,
    min(case when Val3 is not null then Value end) as Val3R,
from D
group by ID, DateField1
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe your query be too much complicated so I'm not sure with using `with` which you can use it but I tested below query and here is [the DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9c1f/3) gives exactly what you want:

```
create table query ([ID] int,
[Value] varchar(2),[DateField1] date,
[Val1] decimal(10,2),[Val2] decimal(10,2),
[Val3] decimal(10,2))

insert into query 
values(1,'R2','2014-01-01',0.3,3.2,3.1),
      (1,'R1','2014-01-02',null,2.2,0.5),
      (1,'R2','2014-01-02',0.7,null,null)
```

---

```
with cte
as
(
select * from query -- your query
)      
select distinct q.ID,q.DateField1,
   isnull(q.val1 ,(select top 1 qq.val1 from cte qq 
                        where qq.ID=q.ID and qq.datefield1=q.datefield1
                        and qq.val1 is not null)) val1,
   isnull(q.val2,(select top 1 qq.val2 from cte qq 
                        where qq.ID=q.ID and qq.datefield1=q.datefield1
                        and qq.val2 is not null)) val2,
   isnull(q.val3,(select top 1 qq.val3 from cte qq 
                        where qq.ID=q.ID and qq.datefield1=q.datefield1
                        and qq.val3 is not null))val3,
    case 
    when q.val1 is null then (select top 1 qq.value from cte qq 
                        where qq.ID=q.ID and qq.datefield1=q.datefield1
                        and qq.val1 is not null)
    else q.value end as val1R,
    case 
    when q.val2 is null then (select top 1 qq.value from cte qq 
                        where qq.ID=q.ID and qq.datefield1=q.datefield1
                        and qq.val2 is not null)
    else q.value end as val2R,
    case 
    when q.val3 is null then (select top 1 qq.value from cte qq 
                        where qq.ID=q.ID and qq.datefield1=q.datefield1
                        and qq.val3 is not null)
    else q.value end as val3R

 from cte q
```

Comment: Definitely works +1, thanks! But @shawnt00's solution is more succinct.

Comment: you are welcome, correct, there is more than one way for it, at the beginning I tried to use a way like that but I told you may have more than one row and also maybe the type of values be varchar and etc, anyway. good luck.